# problem in determining arrow direction in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pygraphviz

I have detected existing arrows and shapes in an image and i want to know ,
how to determine where the arrow is coming from and going to , i have the starting and ending points of each arrow and x ,y,width, height of each other shape .

I tried calculating the slope of each arrow to extend the arrow and check if an intersection occurs but it is not giving good results .

I expected to know what shapes are  connected to each arrow but some arrows are only connected with one shape .

```
#Looping over detected shapes 
for i in range(len(Shapes)-1,0,-1):
    #Check if the shape is an arrow 
    if Shapes[i][4]=="Arrow":
        points=Shapes[i][6]
        StartX = points[0, 0, 0]
        StartY = points[0, 0, 1]
        Ind = np.argmax(points[:, :, 1])
        MaxX = points[Ind, 0, 0]
        Maxy = points[Ind, 0, 1]
       #Calculating Line equation
        m=(Maxy-StartY)/(MaxX-StartX)
        b=StartY-m*StartX
        #loop on every shape to check connected edges
        for j in range(len(Shapes)-1,0,-1):
            #Escape if it is an arrow
            if Shapes[j][4] == "Arrow":
                continue
            #I use the x of the shape to calculate the y of the arrow
            # x is the upper left corner of each shape
            # check every y  from range (X, X+Width of the shape )  
            x = Shapes[j][0]

            while x<Shapes[j][0]+Shapes[j][2]:
                y=m*x+b
                x+=1
                #if the calculated  Y overlaps with the  shape  then it is 
                #connected to that shape
                if y in range(Shapes[j][1]-100,Shapes[j][1]+Shapes[j][3]+100):
                    Shapes[i].append(Shapes[j][7])
                    Found=True
                    break
```

Input Image

[image: Input Image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code so that we could help you improve it ?

Comment: @ma3oun i added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that you are trying to find which shapes the line of each arrow intersects. I see two flaws in your code that might cause an issue, but I don't know if they are what is causing some arrows to only be connected to one shape according to your code.

First, you calculate slope and y-intersection of each arrow. Later, for each shape you see if for that shape's x values, the equation crosses into the y range of that shape. However, when you find the slope and y-intersection, you use division, which could return a float (a non-integer number, such as 2.5). The issue with this is that range() only finds whole numbers. Therefore, if, for example, the slope of an arrow is 2.143, it is likely that when you find the y value of that arrow, it will be a non-whole number and therefore not cross into the range of the y-values of the shape. A solution is to replace the

`if y in range(Shapes[j][1]-100,Shapes[j][1]+Shapes[j][3]+100):`

with

`if y > Shapes[j][1]-100 and y < Shapes[j][1]+Shapes[j][3]+100:`

Also, to run through each shape, you use

`for j in range(len(Shapes)-1,0,-1):`

This means that if `Shapes` had a length of 5, the for loop would set j to  4, 3, 2, and 1 in that order. However, when referring to a list with a length of 5, you can refer from 0 to 4, not from 1 to 4, since the first item in a list has an index of 0, not 1. Therefore, the for loop should read:

`for j in range(len(Shapes)):`

Or, if you have some reason to count downwards, which it doesn't seem like you have but I may be missing something, you can use:

`for j in range(len(Shapes)-1,-1,-1):`

Hope this helps!
-Theo

Comment: @andrewandrew also I didn't mention this, but I'd advise you to try to find a method of making sure the x and y of the arrow where it intersects the shape is within a certain threshold of the actual scope of the arrow. Otherwise, for example, the bottom arrow in the attached picture might be detected as attached to the top oval in addition the the bottom one, since it's line equation might cause it to pass through the top oval even though the arrow itself is hundreds of pixels away.